# Can I build a Delphi multi language project from the command line?

Tags: delphi, command-line, msbuild, build-automation, multilingual

Using Delphi 2009 (or higher) and the ITE (Internal Translation Manager), how can I build the language projects from the command line? The projects are for example

- Project\Languages\DEU\Project_DEU.bdsproj
- Project\Languages\ENG\Project_ENG.bdsproj

Theses bdsproj files are not MSBuild projects, so do I have to call DCC32 and pass all search paths and compiler parameters using a script file, or is there a way to use MSBuild for this task, if I specifiy a special build target?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a separate .groupproj including the .dproj files.